# Python: Raw ICMP socket unable to receive ICMP message

Tags: python, sockets, icmp

l never used python before, and l was asked to build a simple traceroute with python's raw socket. l need to send an UDP to an unreachable port and interpret ICMP to obtain RTT and amount of hops. To test if l actually received ICMP, l changed TTL to 3, and wireshark told me l received ICMP, but my code was not able to pick up that message

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)       
output = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
ttl = 3
destination = socket.gethostbyname("www.youtube.com")
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, ttl)
client.sendto('include some message',(destination,44343))
output.bind((socket.gethostname(),0))
print 'receiving'
data, addr = output.recvfrom(5012)
print data
client.close()
output.close()
```

lt will stuck on the line data, addr = output.recvfrom(5012). What should l do?

Comment: Are you running the script as root? I don't think ordinary users can bind raw sockets.

Comment: Wild guess: put `output.recvfrom()` in a thread and start it BEFORE You send `UDP` packet. If TTL is 3, there's a chance that your code miss it while it gets to receive part.

Comment: My guess is that `socket.gethostname()` is not returning the IP address you want to bind to. By default, on ubuntu for example, the installer puts your hostname in `/etc/hosts` along with an address of `127.0.0.1`. If that is the case on your system, you will be listening for the returned ICMP packets on the localhost interface and you'll never get any there. Either correct the address, or simply don't bind the ICMP socket at all (in which case it should receive ICMP packets from any interface).

Comment: l am running it as administrator, and l will try to not bind it and see if it works. And, if my raw socket started before l send UDP, shouldn't it be ready to accept ICMP when ICMP is sent to me by a router?

Comment: lt simply won't run if l don't bind it. l am using windows. lf l use ipconfig to find my IPV4 address and type it in, it still won't work.